# adding a new phone & tablet module

Tags: android, android-studio, module

I have problem after adding a new phone & tablet module in my project.
I get an error massage like this:

> Cannot access 'androidx.lifecycle.HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory' which is a supertype of 'com.example.favoriteuser.MainActivity'. Check your module classspath for missing or conflicting dependecies.

[image]

Comment: try it implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following dependencies to module-level build.gradle file

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.2.0'
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.2.0"
```